# fast research with nspredicate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nspredicate

In my application i have a large table of around 20.000 items. I am displaying it on tableview. But the search bar is too slow while doing dynamic search. I have read that NSPredicate method is high performance then NSRange.
I don't know how applicate this method.

My code is :

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText
{
    [self.filteredListContent removeAllObjects]; 

    for (Book *book in listContent)
    {
        NSRange range = [book.name rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        // is very very slow
        if (range.location != NSNotFound) 
        {
           [self.filteredListContent addObject:book];
        }
    }
 }
```

Where i must insert NSPredicate, into our out the "for"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains %@", searchText ];
    self.filteredListContent  = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[listContent filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
}
```

Comment: Thk for the aswer, where i push this code? Into the "for" cycle?

Comment: Instead of the loop. This replaces the loop.

Comment: Ok, but i manage the object Book? @"book.name contains %@" ,is  right?

Comment: sorry but not work, filteredListContent is MutableArray while listContent is Array.

Comment: Edited.. Just create a mutable array from an array if you require it to be mutable.

Comment: Thk, but now i received an error: '[<Book 0xe61eb90> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.' I think because i have an object

Comment: Sorry, i wrong to write! Now work! Thk very much for the support.

Comment: I have tested this, work well but the research is always slow. There is another way to fast the research? query by sqlite?

Comment: you'd actually want `contains[c]` if you want it to be a case-insensitive search

Answer (score 2):

If filtering for instance NSArray, you can use

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"job == 'Programmer'"]
[listOfItems filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

if you want to make a fetch request use

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title == %@", aTitle];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"DVD" inManagedObjectContext:moc]];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
// error handling code
[request release];
```

EDIT:

ssteinberg's example is simple and good, just one note - you can modify an operator using the key characters c and d within square braces to specify case and diacritic insensitivity respectively. Example `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[cd] %@", searchString];`